# Printing asterisk pattern using nested for loops in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

This code is intended to print a pattern with asterisk like this
If a number is entered such as 5
Then the program should print the following pattern. It should print * in order according to the number given and then decreasing

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

But it is printing only one line. Please tell me what is the fault here.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int lines,lines2;

    printf("Enter the number of lines : ");
    scanf("%d",&lines);

    lines2=lines;
    for(;lines>0;lines--) {
        for(;lines2>0;lines2--){
            printf("*");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes when debugging a program it's useful to make everything as visible as possible. It might be difficult to see where newlines are being placed in your output. Maybe it'd be helpful to try printing a visible character like "!" instead of "\n" while testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First:** The following line should be placed between two loop:

```
lines2=lines;
```

**Second:** The following line should be placed before the `{` of outer loop:

```
printf("\n");
```

The Final solution is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
int lines,lines2;
printf("Enter the number of lines : ");
scanf("%d",&lines);

   for(;lines>0;lines--)
  {    
       lines2=lines;
       for(;lines2>0;lines2--)
       { 
           printf("*");
       }
       printf("\n");
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines2=lines;
for(;lines>0;lines--)
{    for(;lines2>0;lines2--)
```

You only initialize `lines2` once BEFORE the outer loop; that is why past the first line it is always zero. You should reset it per each line, assigning to current value of `lines`. This one is probably what you wanted to do:

```
for(; lines > 0; --lines) {
    for(lines2 = lines; lines2 > 0; --lines2) {
```

Answer (score 0):

See this! 
It works!

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{ int lines,lines2;
printf("Enter the number of lines : ");
scanf("%d",&lines);
lines2=lines;
for(;lines>0;lines--)
{    for(lines2=lines;lines2>0;lines2--)
   { printf("*");
   }
printf("\n");
}
}
```

Comment: Answers should at least contain correctly formatted code. Please [edit] your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just changed some lines' places. You need to put newline into first loop:

```
int main() {
    int lines,lines2;

    printf("Enter the number of lines : ");
    scanf("%d", &lines);

    for(;lines>0;lines--) {
        lines2=lines;
        for(;lines2>0;lines2--){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```